# select all leaves node in baum laravel

Tags: php, laravel

For a `Category` model I used https://github.com/etrepat/baum package in my laravel app.

Now I want to select all instances of `Category` model that are a leaf.

```
Category::
whichMethodCallToSelectLeafOnly()
->whereIn('category_id' , $categories)
->brands()->syncWithoutDetaching([$request->get('brand_id')]);
```

But I do not know how can I do that ?

Comment: You could just select all nodes where `(right - left) = 1`. Not sure how to do that with Laravel's Eloquent offhand.